# SQL Comparing two tables and inputting data

Tags: mysql

Good Morning

After many attempts to write this correctly, I have to come for assistance. Here is the issue:

Two Tables:

tombstone and person

Both have the same idtombstone column and they both have the same oProv column

I am attempting to compare both tables using the idtombstone column - if the value matches then copy the value in the tombstone.oProv cell to the person.oProv cell

This is what I was using:

```
Update tombstone
Set tombstone.oProv = person.oProv
From tombstone Join person
On tombstone.idtombstone = person.idtombstone
```

Thank you for any assistance
Steve

Comment: You should review the update statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
Update tombstone Join cemetery 
On tombstone.idcemetery = cemetery.idcemetery
Set tombstone.oProv = cemetery.oProv
```

Comment: Hey Arun - Thanks so much - I noticed after I submitted it, I was getting tables mixed up - I will use your code and replace the values as needed. Thanks agian

Comment: You are welcome @SteveFultonU.E. If this answer helped, you should mark this answer as resolved by clicking the tick mark. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)